# Add parent array name into JSON as key:value

Tags: json, key, jq

I have JSON like that:

```
{
  "binance_BTCUSDT": [
    {
      "price": "12/02 00:00",
      "time": "10232.79",
      "achg": -0.006151
    },
    {
      "time": "12/02 17:01",
      "price": "10342.92",
      "achg": -0.007977
    },
  ],
  "binance_ZECBNB": [
    {
      "time": "09/02 03:53",
      "price": "3.052",
      "achg": 0.1
    }
  ],
  "binance_ZENBTC": []
}
```

How to add to any leaf key:value with name of parent array and remove such dividing into arrays at all?

I tried use jq with   `.[][]|= . + {"pair": path(.) }` , but I don't get how to write correctly path().

#### Expected output

```
[
  {
    "pair": "binance_BTCUSDT",
    "price": "12/02 00:00",
    "time": "10232.79",
    "achg": -0.006151
  },
  {
    "pair": "binance_BTCUSDT",
    "time": "12/02 17:01",
    "price": "10342.92",
    "achg": -0.007977
  },
  {
    "pair": "binance_ZECBNB",
    "time": "09/02 03:53",
    "price": "3.052",
    "achg": 0.1
  }
]
```

Comment: Answer from @peak works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: You should accept it, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your input (after correcting the minor error), the following jq filter produces the output shown below:

```
[ to_entries[] | {pair: .key} + .value[] ]
```

#### Output

```
[
  {
    "pair": "binance_BTCUSDT",
    "price": "12/02 00:00",
    "time": "10232.79",
    "achg": -0.006151
  },
  {
    "pair": "binance_BTCUSDT",
    "time": "12/02 17:01",
    "price": "10342.92",
    "achg": -0.007977
  },
  {
    "pair": "binance_ZECBNB",
    "time": "09/02 03:53",
    "price": "3.052",
    "achg": 0.1
  }
]
```

### Variation

If you want to retain an entry corresponding to `{ "binance_ZENBTC": []}`, then the following filter would be appropriate:

```
[to_entries[] | {pair: .key} + (.value[] // {}) ]
```